# how do I get company ID wise backup or restore the data

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I have a mini account software. In this software I can store multiple company data. The data is stored in SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

In current database I have a User table which stores all user names, a Company Master table which stores company details like name,address, session etc. and user ID as FK with user table. Next is tran table which link with company Master and stores vouchers details and others table link to tran tabel like bill, payment etc.

The app is build for small companies and professionals who keep & maintain there their client data. In that scenario all data is separate and mutually independedent. In case of the small company they maintain all subsidiary company's account related data in a single app. Some time they receipt or send any one subsidiary company data to that company or any government body or Audit firms. like mobile phone contacts, I can send all contacts or any selected contact.

Users used to select his/her company first form company Master and then add/edit reference data or view report on the basis of selected company ID.

Now my problem is the data volume is become very high on some client places because of 50 to 60 companies data are stored in a single database and how I get company ID wise backup or restore the data. Is filegroup of sql server can help on this matter? I have no knowledge of filegroup.

Please help me.

Comment: There is no built in function for that, you will have to program it yourself, because it is specific to your db design. What is 'very high number of records'?

Comment: Thank you VdOHNAL, I want to know what is best way for db design. separate database for separate company and a master database for all company or store all data in a single database which is currently working? But I can't take backup for single company.

Comment: This is a very broad question and cannot be answered without detailed knowledge of your database model and your data.

Comment: In current database I have a user Table which stores all user name, a Company Master table which stores company details like name,address, session etc. and user ID as FK with user table. next is tran table which link with company Master and stores vouchers details and others table link to tran tabel like bill, payment etc.

Comment: This is really very little information to get insight on how your app works. Though it seems to me (but it is just a guess) that it would not be very wise to split your data into multiple databases. Why do your clients need partial database backup by company?

Comment: Thanks VDohnal, The app build for small company's and professionals who keep & maintain there client data.  In that scenario all data is separate and not depended etch other. In the case of small company they maintain all subsidiary company's account related data in a single apps. some time they receipt or send any one subsidiary company data to that company or any government body or Audit firms.    like mobile phone contacts, I can send all contacts or any selected contact. Is filegroup of sql server can help on this matter? I have no knowledge of filegroup. I just find it on searching.

Answer (score 0):

Do not split your SQL database into multiple SQL databases (either do not create more filegroups etc.) just because you need to get data filtered by the `CompanyId`. Everytime when your Client would need to create a new Company, your application would have to create a new database for it. This would also quite complicate things like app updates.

If you do not face any grave performance problems - like when using SQL Express and your client database is 9 GB (max. database size for Express is 10 GB)  - leave 1 database for 1 client.

Be sure all your related tables are well indexed by the `CompanyID` column. Then you can provide means to export data by CompanyID from your application - custom reports, exports to csv files, Excel etc.

Database backup file is usually not used for passing data to other applications. Its goal is to assure disaster recovery - when the disk fails etc. then your client will be able to recover easily. On contrary when he would have 50 database files in place of just 1 he would have hard time restoring all those databases properly.